# How to get coordinate on the chart

Tags: activex, teechart

I have used following way to get x-axis and y-axis co-ordinate. But I'm unable to get y axis co-ordinates.

```
**/*X axis max*/**
double xMaxAxisBottom = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetMaximum();// try to get x axis
double xMaxAxisBottomPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(xMaxAxisBottom); // Here trying to position based on x-axis co-ordinate

**/*X axis min*/**
double xMinAxisBottom = m_reschedChart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetMinimum();//// try to get x axis minimum
double xMinAxisBottomPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().MinXValue();

**/*Y axis max*/**
double xMaxAxisLeft = m_reschedChart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetMaximum();
    double xMaxAxisLeftPixelPos = m_reschedChart.GetAxis().GetLeft().MaxXValue();
**/*Y axis min*/**
double xMinAxisLeft = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetMinimum();
double xMinAxisLeftPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().MinXValue();

**/*X axis length*/**
double xAxisBottomLen = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetEndPosition() - m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetStartPosition();
double xAxisBottomLenPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(xAxisBottomLen);
**/*Y axis length*/**
double yAxisLeftLen = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetEndPosition() - m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetStartPosition();
double xAxisLeftLenPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(yAxisLeftLen);
**/*X origin*/**
double dXstartPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetStartPosition();
double dXstartPixelPos = m_reschedChart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(dXstartPos);
**/*Y origin*/**
double dYStartPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetStartPosition();
double dYStartPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().CalcXPosValue(dYStartPos);
```

let me know if i am making any mistake to find the co-ordinates. 
I wanted to find below mention co-ordinated using above code.
    1   X axis max
    2   X axis min
    3   Y axis max
    4   Y axis min
    5   X axis length
    6   Y axis length
    7   X origin
    8   Y origin
    9   Label font size

Please let me know your view.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The chart needs to be drawn to use these methods. They need some internal properties to be initialized to work as expected.
You can force a chart repaint before calling them with:

```
m_Chart.GetEnvironment().InternalRepaint();
```

---

**EDIT**:

Since you seem to be calling these functions at OnAfterDraw event, you don't need to force a chart repaint. However, I'd suggest you some modifications in your code.

- I see you are using `m_Chart` and also `m_reschedChart`. Make sure you are using the correct TChart variable.
- Your variables start with `x` and `y` but thay also include `Bottom` or `Left` depending on the axis they refer. This is redundant and increments the chances to write a mistake (ie **x**MaxAxis**Left**).
- `CalcXPosValue` has to be used with Horizontal axes and `CalcYPosValue` with Vertical axes. So you shouldn't call `GetLeft().CalcXPosValue`.
- `CalcXPosValue` and `CalcYPosValue` are functions to convert axis values to screen pixels.
- `MinXValue` and `MaxXValue` are to be used with Horizontal Axes while `MinYValue` and `MaxYValue` are to be used with Vertical Axes.
- `GetMinimum` returns the same than `MinXValue`/`MinYValue`, and `GetMaximum` returns the same than `MaxXValue`/`MaxYValue`. All these functions return Axis values, not screen pixels.
- GetStartPosition and EndStartPosition are thought to modify the Axis length and by default they use percentages as explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/activex/tutorials/tutorial4.htm#PositionPercent), so `GetStartPosition - EndStartPosition` is always zero. And I think  `CalcXPosValue(GetStartPosition - EndStartPosition)` is conceptually wrong too. Note `IStartPos` and `IEndPos` give you the Start and End positions in pixels. See the TeeChart ActiveX Tutorials [here](http://www.teechart.net/docs/).

Find below the modified code I suggest you:

```
**/*X axis max*/**
double maxAxisBottom = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetMaximum();// try to get x axis
double maxAxisBottomPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(xMaxAxisBottom); // Here trying to position based on x-axis co-ordinate

**/*X axis min*/**
double minAxisBottom = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetMinimum();//// try to get x axis minimum
double minAxisBottomPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().CalcXPosValue(minAxisBottom);

**/*Y axis max*/**
double maxAxisLeft = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetMaximum();
double maxAxisLeftPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().CalcYPosValue(maxAxisLeft);

**/*Y axis min*/**
double minAxisLeft = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetMinimum();
double minAxisLeftPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().CalcYPosValue(minAxisLeft);
```

Now you already know the position of the four squares in screen pixels so you can ie draw a rectangle using them to check it:

```
m_Chart.getCanvas().Rectangle(minAxisBottomPixelPos, minAxisLeftPixelPos, maxAxisBottomPixelPos, maxAxisLeftPixelPos);
```

If you also want or need the sizes of the axes in pixels, you can do:

```
**/*X axis length*/**
double axisBottomLenPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetIEndPos() - m_Chart.GetAxis().GetBottom().GetIStartPos();

**/*Y axis length*/**
double axisLeftLenPixelPos = m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetIEndPos() - m_Chart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetIStartPos();
```

And you can check they are correctly calculated:

```
m_Chart.getCanvas().Rectangle minAxisBottomPixelPos, maxAxisLeftPixelPos, minAxisBottomPixelPos + axisBottomLenPixelPos, maxAxisLeftPixelPos + axisLeftLenPixelPos
```

Comment: I already used InternalRepaint API. and i am calling above code inside OnAfterDrawTchart function. so drawing is not a problem. In above code is there any place where we need to call CalcYPosValue API instead of CalcXPosValue.